# MERGE statement yields binding error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

I tried this code:

```
 Merge fact_table as target 
using( select top 1 idDateDeb,PK_Date, Week_Of_Year from dbo.dim_date_Debut)
as source 
on cast(source.PK_Date as date)=cast(dbo.FACT_TABLE.DATE_DEBUT_ALRM as date)
when matched then update set target.ID_TEMP_DEB=source.idDateDeb;
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 
>   
> The multi-part identifier "dbo.FACT_TABLE.DATE_DEBUT_ALRM" could not be bound.

I am trying to do something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743900/fact-table-ssis-sqlserver-r2008).

Comment: I suggest instead of linking to another question you describe what you're trying to do here (especially if it is *different* from the other question - otherwise this should be closed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Merge dbo.fact_table as target 
using( select top 1 idDateDeb,PK_Date, Week_Of_Year from dbo.dim_date_Debut)
as source 
on cast(source.PK_Date as date)=cast(target.DATE_DEBUT_ALRM as date)
when matched then update set target.ID_TEMP_DEB=source.idDateDeb;
```

You've aliased (`dbo.`) `fact_table` as `target`, so the parser will be expecting to see `target`, not `dbo.FACT_TABLE`.

Comment: i did this code but i didn't set IdDateDeb on Fact_Table :s:   0 rows affected si think i have to do triiger when data inserted on fact_Table i getId and put it on id_tem_deb but i don't know how to do it

Comment: i tried this code but O rows affected what is the problem ?
Merge fact_table as target using( select top 1 idDatefin,PK_Date_fin,
Week_Of_Year
from dbo.dim_date_fin)as source 
on cast(source.PK_Date_fin as date)=cast(target.DATE_fin_ALaRM as date)
when matched then
update set target.ID_TEMP_DEB=source.idDatefin,
 target.NUMEROSEMAINE=source.Week_Of_Year;
heeeeelp please ;(